# Mempool streaming

Tags: node, rpc, api, mempool

How would you go about pulling live mempool data like https://tzflow.com/? I have a private node and I've looked at the `/chains/main/mempool/pending_operations` endpoint, but I'm not sure how to stream pending transactions.

Answer (score 1):

tzflow.com uses the `/chains/main/mempool/monitor_operations` RPC to get a stream of operations submitted to the mempool of one representative node.

As mentioned elsewhere here, the node closes this stream on each new block.

Comment: Aha! This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`/chains/main/mempool/monitor_operations` streams pending transactions, but the connection is closed when the node gets a new head block. You can do this in a loop to keep streaming.

(**Edited** to replace `pending` with `monitor` in the RPC :-))

Comment: In the body of the response, I don't see anything marked as pending. It shows applied, refused, outdated, etc.